# Keras interated training

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am using manually k-folder data generator to train my neural network which is built by Keras. The process is some thing below:

```
def build_model():
   encoder = Dense(...)(input)
   encoder = Dense(...)(encoder)
   decoder = Dense(...)(encoder)
   decoder = Dense(...)(decoder)
   autoencoder = Model(input_layer, decoder)
   autoencoder.compile(...)
   return autoencoder
def train_model(...):
   autoencoder = build_model()
   autoencoder.fit()
   return autencoder

for train_index, test_index in KFold(X, 10):
   trained_model = train_model(X_train, X_test)
```

This is just a simple process I used. My confusion is when I doing this training process in the loop, I am feeling the neural network is not initialized every time.  It looks like the training process is continuing based on the previous result, the trained weights of each neuron are still in the memory.

I am wondering is there a way to clear the memory for each training loop? Or this process should be OK, and I am safe to train this model over and over again?

Comment: Why do you "feel" that? What makes you think it's not being reset?

Comment: Because if I close the terminal and reopen it, train the model once a time, the performance some times good, some times bad. But if I use a loop to train the model in the same terminal, the performance somehow has a trend of increasing, and then drop. Looks like I begin with a small batch_size, and with the increasing of the batch size, the performance is increasing and then decreasing.

Comment: Maybe it is my delusion. I just want to make sure about it.